# CentOS 7 : serial (COM7) sessions are maintained even after closing the terminal

Tags: linux, centos

On my Linux (CentOS7), I am running a serial connection to access the Bash shell.

After rebooting, my system asks me a prompt to login, but once the user authenticates itself and closes the session from the  button, the serial connection never asks to authenticate. It always gives the bash prompt directly.

I want to harden my system so that serial connection always asks for authenticating whenever I open the new terminal.

Comment: Do you log out when you're done, or just detach the serial connection (which is effectively just a keyboard)?